# Collapsible table row does not extend past cell width

Tags: css, angularjs, html-table, accordion

I have a table with a +/- sign that is clickable.  When a user clicks on it, it opens up a div below to reveal more details.  The issue I'm running into is the collapsible div is only as wide as one table column, and i can't seem to get it to be full width.

Here is a screenshot of the table with collapsed rows:

[image]

And this is what it looks like when expanded:

[image]

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="work in item.work_history | orderBy: '-to' track by $index">
   <div class="table-cell" style="vertical-align: middle;" >
      <a class="flex collapsed"
         ng-class="{'accordion-toggle collapsed':work.campaign.length>0}"
         ng-if="work.campaign.length>0" data-toggle="collapse"
         ng-click="c.campaign(work)" href="#{{work.sys_id}}"
         role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseDetails">
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="table-cell">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit Work History"
         ng-click="c.newEntry(work.sys_id,'x_dnf_gw_found_work_history','newWork');">
        Edit
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="table-cell">
      {{work.work_name}}
   </div>
   <div class="table-cell">
      {{work.from}}
   </div>
   <div class="table-cell">
      {{work.to}}
   </div>
   <div class="table-cell">
      <button title="Add Campaign" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs"
              ng-click="c.newEntry(-1, 'x_campaigns','newWork')">
         Add Campaign
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="{{campaignDetails}}">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="campaigns in c.campaign_details">
         {{campaigns.from}} - {{campaigns.to}}: {{campaigns.camp}}
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I know why the expanded details are showing up within one table cell, but I'm not sure how to fix this styling issue.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `class "table-row"` to your collapsible division

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="work in item.work_history | orderBy: '-to' track by $index">
   <div class="table-cell" style="vertical-align: middle;" >
      <a class="flex collapsed" ng-class="{'accordion-toggle collapsed':work.campaign.length>0}" ng-if="work.campaign.length>0" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="c.campaign(work)" href="#{{work.sys_id}}" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseDetails"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="table-cell">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit Work History" ng-click="c.newEntry(work.sys_id,'x_dnf_gw_found_work_history','newWork');">Edit</a>
   </div>
   <div class="table-cell">
      {{work.work_name}}
   </div>
   <div class="table-cell">
      {{work.from}}
   </div>
   <div class="table-cell">
      {{work.to}}
   </div>
   <div class="table-cell">
      <button title="Add Campaign" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs" ng-click="c.newEntry(-1, 'x_campaigns','newWork')">Add Campaign</button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse table-row" id="{{campaignDetails}}">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="campaigns in c.campaign_details">
         {{campaigns.from}} - {{campaigns.to}}: {{campaigns.camp}}
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```